# Open Bootstrap modal using Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a situation where I want to open a Bootstrap modal dialog from my controller after I execute some code on the controller. I want to show modal on top of the opened web page and after submitting a form on that page. A modal is not shown on every form submit but only when a certain exception has been thrown. My modal code is:

```
<div id="sameCompany" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body" id="existToDoModalBody">
            @ViewBag.ExceptionMessageSameCompany
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this? I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.
Thanks a lot, in advance.

Comment: send ajax call and after success show popup?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it is not success what I am after :). I have 2 places in my controller on which i catch two exceptions. For one I open new page, for the other I need to show a modal dialog without going to another page.

Comment: so what you need to do is call action via ajax and show popup, isn't it?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad actually, for showing a modal i'm not entering a catch block, but i'm "manually" catching an exception message in a ViewBag. maybe I could use ajax, but i kindly ask you to elaborate on how exactly can i do it. I think i need to call a partial view after i "manually" catch an exception.

Comment: yes return exception with a flag in ajax call put it in a div in popup and display popup, I can provide some pseudocode as well

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Please provide some pseudocode, it would be great. You can put it as an answer so I can vote for it

Answer (score 0):

ok Kiriz, the first you have to do is create two views one VeiwExecuteSubmit and ViewLoadModal, every view should have one function in the controller principal,when you execute the submit, before you return data to the success call in this part you can call the function por render of view the modal, or if you want to wait that the submit is end call, re-call the controller function for render the viewModal....

Comment: it would be great if you could provide some code, I am not getting it 100%.

Comment: The process its maybe large , but for load the modal in the view you have a execute one calll with ajax to controller and load like a iframe the modal "return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");", for execute the submit to controller use this "http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/" in the action of submit after the task ist done you return the redirectToAction for load the modal,,,,,